# Python: test a function contained inside another function

Tags: python, pytest

I'm working with Python3, `pytest` and `unittest`. I have a function named `parent` that contains another function named `child`.

How can I test the inner function?

```
def parent():
    ...

    def child():
        ....

    ...
```

Comment: I think you can only call the function from within the parent function. Its called incapsulation :)

Comment: [Mu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_(negative)#"Unasking"_the_question), you can't. At least not in a reasonable way.

Comment: If the function is contained inside another function, it is an implementation detail of the parent function and should not be tested separately. You should be able to test the parent function without knowing it's calling another function. If you need to call the inner function separately (and therefore test it), it should not be nested.

Comment: You can't call it directly.  You can only call it indirectly by calling `parent()`.

Comment: I'm quite sure this has been answered before, but can't find it... basically, the inner function is created _each time you enter the outer function_, so there is no way to test it, as it does not exist before the call.

Comment: @MrBean Whether that's actually true depends on the optimisations present in your flavour of Python, but certainly conceptually that's how you must think about it, yes.

Answer (score 0):

You can only call the function from within the parent function. Its called incapsulation :)

```
def parent():
    def child():
        print('World')
    print('Hello')
    child()
    print('Hello')
    child()
    print('Hello')
    child()

parent()
```

Outputs:

```
Hello
World
Hello
World
Hello
World
```

Answer (score -1):

It depends on how you are using the child method but you could use a class instead:

To test: [python unit testing methods inside of classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23369588/python-unit-testing-methods-inside-of-classes)

```
class Parent:
    @classmethod
    def child(cls):
        print('hello')

    @classmethod
    def run(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        cls.child()

Parent.run()
Parent.child()
```